# ORACLE ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: oracle

I am having an error ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined.
The column is NARRATION which is defined in both the tables "view_accvoucherrep" and "view_accchequedetails". When I am using alias in search option it working fine. But cannot be written like that.
When we are running without the search condition i.e. "UPPER(NARRATION) LIKE '%CHEQUE' it's working fine and displaying all the results.

```
SELECT *  FROM
(
SELECT 
a.LOCATIONNAME,DEBIT,CREDIT, 
a.NARRATION as NARRATION,
a.VOUCHERTYPE

from view_accvoucherrep a  
left join view_accchequedetails dep_chq on dep_chq.locationcode=a.locationcode 
where a.TRANYEAR='2014_2015' 
and UPPER(NARRATION) LIKE '%CHEQUE%'
)
```

Comment: You knew the answer? Narration column is in both tables.. So, when you don't prefix the alias, how does the database know which one to choose?

Comment: It's Ok.I got the resolution. We can change the join conditions and could select the columns and ignore the narration coulmn from the accchequedetails table.
like join (select locationcode,column1,column2,...... from view_accchequedetails) dep_chq on dep_chq.locationcode=a.locationcode
This is working

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the column alias in where. You have to use the colum name there, with table alias

```
SELECT *  FROM
(
SELECT 
a.LOCATIONNAME,DEBIT,CREDIT, 
a.NARRATION as NARRATION,
a.VOUCHERTYPE

from view_accvoucherrep a  
left join view_accchequedetails dep_chq on dep_chq.locationcode=a.locationcode 
where a.TRANYEAR='2014_2015' 
and UPPER(a.NARRATION) LIKE '%CHEQUE%'
)
```

Comment: Can we modify the join condition because the search condition is defined for number of other pages also but in this it is not working.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the expected result?